# Killing Vectors in Schwarzschild Metric

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

Given the Schwarzschild metric with $(-,+,+,+)$ signature,

$$\text ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)dt^2+\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2)$$

the lack of dependence of the metric on $t$ and $\phi$ allow us to read off the Killing vectors $K_1=\partial_t$ and $K_2=\partial_{\phi}$. These vectors, in their coordinate representations, are given by

$$K_1=\left(-\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right),0,0,0\right)$$

$$K_2=\left(0,0,0,r^2\sin^2\theta\right)$$

**How does one immediately read off those vector components for $K_1$ and $K_2$? What is the logic behind reading them off? How would I "read off the Killing vectors" if I, while maintaining no explicit dependence on $t$ or $\phi$, added some off-diagonal terms to the metric? Please help me intuitively understand what's going on here.**

Comment: your question as it stands is not very clear. What you really want to know are the *covariant* components of the killing vectors, given the simple *contravariant* ones. You just go from the contravariant to the covariant components simply by multiplying with the metric as described by Chris White in his answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If all components of the metric are independent of some particular $x^\nu$, then you have the killing vector $\vec{K}$ with components $K^\mu = \delta^\mu_\nu$. That is, the *contravariant* form just has a constant in the appropriate slot and zeros elsewhere. In Schwarzschild, you have $K^\mu = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $R^\mu = (0, 0, 0, 1)$ ($\vec{K}$ and $\vec{R}$ being your $K_1$ and $K_2$, respectively).

To find the *covariant* forms, simply lower with the metric. In Schwarzschild we have
\begin{align}
K_\mu & = g_{\mu\nu} K^\nu = g_{\mu t} = \big({-}(1-2M/r), 0, 0, 0\big) \\
R_\mu & = g_{\mu\nu} R^\nu = g_{\mu\phi} = \big(0, 0, 0, r^2 \sin^2\!\theta\big).
\end{align}
This is where off-diagonal terms would come in. For example, in Boyer-Lindquist we also have no $t$-dependence, so we have $K^\mu = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ and
$$ K_\mu = g_{\mu t} = \big({-}(1-2Mr/\Sigma), 0, 0, -(2Mar/\Sigma)\sin^2\!\theta\big), $$
where the fourth component is precisely $g_{t\phi}$.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much. This makes so much sense.

Comment: @user10851 is this related to the fact, that if some $\frac{dP_{x_0}}{d\tau}=0$ and $K^{\mu}$ is a Killing vector, then $K^{\mu}P_{\mu}=P_{x_0}$?

Answer (score 6):

**Conceptually:**

If we leave the mathematical definition aside for a while, we can **define** the killing vector:

> *Killing vector $K^\mu(x)$ **leaves metric unchanged** under infinitesimal coordinate changes*

**Time coordinate**

Change in $t$ does nothing to the metric:

> Change in $t\rightarrow t+dt$:
>
> $g_{\mu \nu}=g_{\mu \nu}(t)=g_{\mu \nu}(t+dt)=g_{\mu \nu}$

So one of the killing vectors should be along $t$:

> $K^\mu=(1,0,0,0)$

That's it!

*Note: The form you have has the indice lowered: $K_\mu=g_{\mu \nu}K^\nu=(g_{\mu0}K^0,0,0,0)=(-(1-2M/r),0,0,0)$*

Comment: Note: Similar logic can be used for any metric. Example: If $g_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow g_{\mu \nu}(x,y,z)$, then one of the killing vectors should be $K^\mu=(1,0,0,0)$